# Magento - How to change font-size for totals in order email?

Tags: email, magento, templates, font-size

After upgrading from 1.8 to 1.9.1 the font-size of my order emails is changed for the block totals and I can't figure out how to change it.

At the moment it looks like this: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-26791263/Unbenannt.jpg.html

I would like to change the font-sie to 12px like the rest of the email text.

Here my template from the backend:

```
<h1></h1>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.Stil1 {
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
}
.Stil2 {font-size: 12px}
.Stil4 {font-size: 10px}
-->
</style>
<body style="background:#FFFFFF; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<footer style="background:#FFFFFF; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<div style="background:#FFFFFF; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
        <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
            <!-- [ header starts here] -->
            <tr>                   
                <td valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><div align="right">
                <p><a href="{{store url=""}}"><img src="{{skin url="images/logo.jpg" _area='frontend'}}" alt="{{var store.getFrontendName()}}"  style="margin-bottom:10px;" border="0"/></a>
</p>
                <p>Shop Name <span class="Stil4">Shop Adress </span></p>
                </div></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- [ middle starts here] -->
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <h1 class="Stil2" style="font-size:12px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0;"">Sehr geehrte Kundin, sehr geehrter Kunde, </h1>
                    <p class="Stil2">Vielen Dank f&uuml;r Ihre Bestellung. <br>
Die Bearbeitung Ihrer Bestellung sollte innerhalb der n&auml;chsten 5-7 Tage erfolgen. Sollten Sie dann nicht von uns h&ouml;ren, oder keine Ware erhalten, m&ouml;chten wir Sie bitten, sich mit uns in Verbindung zu setzen. </p>
                    <span class="Stil2">Vielen Dank, <br>
                    Ihr Team                    </span>
            <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0;">&nbsp;</p>              
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <h2 style="font-size:18px; font-weight:normal; margin:0;"><span class="Stil1">Ihre Bestellung  #{{var order.increment_id}} <small>(get&auml;tigt am  {{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}})</small></span></h2>                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th align="left" width="325" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;"><span class="Stil2"> Rechnungsadresse:</span></th>
                            <th width="10"></th>
                            <th align="left" width="325" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;"><span class="Stil2">Zahlart:</span></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border-left:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-right:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-top:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                {{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}                      <br>    
                                {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerEmail()}}                    </td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border-left:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-right:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-top:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                {{var payment_html}}{{var order.customer_taxvat}}                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <br/>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th align="left" width="325" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;"><span class="Stil2">Lieferadresse:</span></th>
                            <th width="10"></th>
                            <th align="left" width="325" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;"><span class="Stil2">Porto:</span></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border-left:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-right:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-top:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                {{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}
&nbsp;                            </td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border-left:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-right:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-top:1px solid #EAEAEA;">Shipping Fees &nbsp;                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <br/>
                    {{/depend}}
                    {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}  <br>   
<span class="Stil2">Bestellkommentar:</span>
                    <p style="font-size:12px; margin:0 0 10px 0">{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}</p>             </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

and template style:
    body,td { color:#2f2f2f; font:11px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

this worked well before but now the size of the totals block is much bigger. Can anyone suggest me where to add the correct tag to edit the font-size?

Comment: this is working for me,please try this one https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182229/transactional-email-totals

Comment: this is working for me,use link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182229/transactional-email-totals

Answer (score 0):

Try adding styles to the following template:

```
/app/design/frontend/**base/default**/template/sales/order/totals.phtml
```

or check the same file to your custom theme.

Comment: When I searched through the web for a solution there was mentioned that this method would affect other parts where totals.phtml is called, so I would like to change only in my emails. Could you advise me how to add a font-size method in this file? Then I would try where the changes are visible.

Comment: working answer.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182229/transactional-email-totals

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the font size on your local.xml. eg:

```
<sales_email_order_items>
    <reference name="order_totals">
        <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>style="padding:6px 9px;font-size:12px;"</value></action>
        <action method="setValueProperties"><value>style="padding:6px 9px;font-size:12px;"</value></action>
    </reference>
</sales_email_order_items>
```